# Sending email while the app runs in background on iPhone

Tags: iphone, background, scheduled-tasks

I want to develop an iPhone app which will continuously run in background.
I want to send email to a particular email ID at definite interval of time while the app runs in the background.
How do I do this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 3):

First off, you should done more research, not just ask how to do this. Where are not here to code for you.

Second, How do you plan to run your app in background? Only apps that play audio, track user position (GPS) or are VOIP clients are allowed to run in background.

Third, you can't send an e-mail without user interaction, unless you send the mail via either a SMTP server directly or use some kind of webservice.